# Selecting most recent timestamp row and getting values from a column with a Variant DataType

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I hope the title makes some sense, I'm open to suggestions if I should make it more readable.

I have a temp table in Snowflake called BI_Table_Temp. It has 2 columns Load_DateTime with a datatype Timestamp_LTZ(9) and JSON_DATA which is a Variant datatype that's has nested records from a JSON file. I want to query this table which I then plan to ingest to another table but I want to make sure I always get the most recent Load_DateTime row.

I've tried this, which works but it shows me the Load_DateTime column and I don't want that I just want to get the values from the JSON_DATA row that has the max Load_DateTime timestamp:

```
SELECT
MAX(Load_DateTime),
transactions.value:id::string as id
transactions.value:value2::string as account_value
transactions.value:value3::string as new_account_value
FROM BI_Table_Temp,
LATERAL FLATTEN (JSON_DATA:transactions) as transactions
GROUP BY transactions.value
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple option:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT Load_DateTime 
    , transactions.value:id::string as id
    , transactions.value:value2::string as account_value
    , transactions.value:value3::string as new_account_value
  FROM BI_Table_Temp,
  LATERAL FLATTEN (JSON_DATA:transactions) as transactions
), max_load AS (
  SELECT MAX(Load_DateTime) Load_DateTime, id
  FROM data, 
  GROUP BY id
)

SELECT transactions.value:id::string as id
    , transactions.value:value2::string as account_value
    , transactions.value:value3::string as new_account_value
FROM data
JOIN max_load
USING (id, Load_DateTime)
```

Since `transactions.value` is a variant, I'm guessing that for `GROUP BY transactions.value` you really mean `GROUP BY transactions.value:id`.

Comment: Hi @Felipe, thank you for responding. I've just tried your code but I get the following error:
SQL compilation error: error line 16 at position 0 invalid identifier 'TRANSACTIONS.VALUE'. which is coming form the second select statement's  first line: 
transactions.value:id::string as id
I'm trying to get the last Load_DateTime from the BI_Table_Temp, and use the values from that JSON_DATA row (which is a variant data type and I'm using transactions.value to get the nested values from that row). I then intend to copy this into another table

Comment: It would help a lot if in the question you could post a running query. I know the starting one you posted will not work, as it's even missing commas. I just tried my best with what you provided. With that said - I just added a missing comma to my answer. Can you try again?

Comment: Hi @Felipe thanks for brining up that error, I've just fixed the missing comma in my query and currently it works with my change but I dont want it to show the Load_DateTime column which it is since its in the select statement and I want to make sure I'm always getting the last Load_DateTime column from my temp table. I'm still getting the same error (also I've removed the comma in your query after "data" before "GROUP BY" because that was throwing me an error).